# Counting the occurence of a word in a text file using python

Tags: python, full-text-search

I copied the code from a tutorial to count the number of occurrences of a word in a text file but for some reason the program miscounts by a lot (it seems to max out at 6).  I have tested it using text from different files but for some reason it is not correctly counting.

This is my code:

```
search = input("Input your search term: ") 
found = 0

with open ("search.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data: 
        if search.casefold() in line.casefold():  
            found += 1

    print(found)
```

Is the problem with my code?

Comment: ```found += 1``` should be indented  to be inside the ```if``` condition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The indentation problem was with my copying and pasting but not with the original code itself...or I wouldn't have been able to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you change your code to this:

```
search = input("Input your search term: ")  
found = 0

with open ("search.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data: 
        if search.casefold() in line.casefold():  
            found += line.casefold().count(search.casefold())

    print(found)
```

Would this make a difference? Your code count only once if the word appears multiple times in a line.